# Foreign retirement contribution deductibility?

Tags: united-states, tax-deduction, retirement-plan, dtaa, france

Contributors,

I have a very specific question.  I am a dual European-American citizen.  I live in France.  I declare my income on French investment accounts to the US, and am generally tax-compliant.

I contribute each year to a French tax-exempt retirement plan, called a PERP. In France, contributions to this plan are deductible from income (for tax purposes), up to around 10% of income.  My question is this:  Under the US-France tax treaty, are these contributions also deductible from US income, or not?

Thanks for your replies.

Robert

Answer (score 1):

I am not an accountant or financial advisor.

[Look at the relevant tax treaty.](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-trty/france.pdf)

[This IRS explanatory document](https://www.treasury.gov/resource-center/tax-policy/treaties/Documents/tefrench06.pdf) says:

> In the United States, the plans that are automatically eligible for benefits under
>   paragraph 2 include a French pension or other retirement arrangement organized under
>   the French social security legislation.

which also has

> an individual, with respect to dividends beneficially owned by
>   such individual and derived from investment in a retirement arrangement
>   under which the contributions or the accumulated earnings receive taxfavored
>   treatment under U.S. law

under paragraph 4(vi)(e)(ii)(cc) (how's that for indenting!).

Bottom line: it's not clear to me, but it sounds like the contributions may be.

You need to consult someone knowledgeable about the treaty!